# Azure Policy which only allows RGs to be created via IAC?

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to restrict the manner of which resource groups are created on my Azure Subscriptions.

I only want to allow the creation of RGs via Azure Pipelines using Terraform.

Is this possible? and how can i attack this?

THank you

Comment: I belive i can also do this via allowing only the Serive Principles to create RGs?

Comment: It can only be controlled via RBAC by restricting user/sp/managed identity access. Azure doesn't know whether it's IAC/rest API/manually.

Answer (score 0):

- *You can't achieve it using Azure policy rather you need to create custom role by providing necessary permissions using RBAC and assign it to respective scope.*
- *Also, if in case you are using Azure blueprints then I would suggest first to check deny assignments.*
- *Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli) for creating resource Group using terraform.*
- *Also, you can go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544294/azure-custom-policy-to-limit-creation-of-a-resourc.html) which has related discussions.*